# Flutter Facebook Sharing Crashes iOS App - How to Resolve?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Everything works fine up until Facebook gets called, and then I receive the following error and crash reporterror **[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]** Any help is greatly appreciated! [image: Crash Image]

[image: infoplist file]